# TFS 2013 build of windows store app fails with "The "GenerateAppxPackageRecipe" task failed unexpectedly."

Tags: c#, msbuild, windows-8.1, tfsbuild, appx

I have a VS2013 project for a Windows 8.1 Store App written in C#/XAML. I've configured a build using a TFS 2013 build template to build the solution for my project. There are a few other projects in the solution that are building fine (database project, web project, windows service project, WPF client app project).

When the Windows Store App builds I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets (1224): The "GenerateAppxPackageRecipe" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionaryTSource,TKey,TElement
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.DumpResourceIndexMap..ctor(ITaskItem[] indexedPayloadFiles)
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.ResourceIndexMap.Create(String projectDir, String makePriExtensionPath, ITaskItem[] indexedPayloadFiles)
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.GenerateAppxPackageRecipe.ExecuteImplementation()
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.AppxPackagingTaskHelper.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.GenerateAppxPackageRecipe.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()
```

I'm passing the following parameters to the MSBuild Arguments in the build configuration: /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /tv:12.0. Also in the Package.appxmanifest settings under the "Packaging" tab I've set the Generate app bundle setting to Never. I'm not sure what other settings may be relevant here so please let me know if there are other details I can provide that would help you understand my situation better.

The project builds and packages fine on my development system. If I run the Project --> Store --> Create App Packages... wizard from within VS2013 it generates the .appx file.

I really don't know where to look next. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I took a fresh look at the problem today and have managed to end up with a functional build. The problem seems to be with our customized build template from TFS 2012. It turns out the Xaml activity for running MSBuild in TFS 2012 is named MSBuild and for TFS 2013 it is named RunMSBuild. The 2012 flavor of the activity explicitly runs the MSBuild.exe from the .NET Framework 4.0 installation typically found here: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319. The 2013 flavor of the activity runs the MSBuild.exe from the TFS 2013 installation of MSBuild typically found here: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin. In order to build Windows Store Apps for Win8.1 you must use MSBuild for 2013.

Our customized build template provided us with automatic assembly versioning in the scheme we prefer which is why I was using that template. It seems I will have to use the new TFS 2013 template (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml) as a basis for our updated custom template from here.

Hope this information might be useful to someone someday. Thanks!